# How to use `com.jetbrains.env.PyEnvTestCase` in my unit tests?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, pycharm, intellij-plugin, intellij-python

I am developing a plugin for `PyCharm` which uses custom `PythonConsoleRunnerFactory`.

Currently am trying to write unit tests to cover the created class and I have found at source code of `PyCharm` that there is `PyEnvTestCase` class that is used for console testing but I don't know how to include this class in my project.

I am using `Gradle` as a build tool. Here is my `gradle` build script:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "0.6.5"
}


group = "com.uriyyo.evaluate_async_code"
version = "1.8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13")
}

configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnit()
}

intellij {
    version = project.properties["ideaVersion"].toString()
    type = "PC"
    pluginName = "evaluate-async-code"
    downloadSources = project.properties["downloadIdeaSources"] == "true"
    updateSinceUntilBuild = false
    setPlugins("terminal", "python-ce")
}
```

Is there a way to include `PyEnvTestCase` to be available for tests?